# How do I know which character is in a position in a string?

Tags: python, string

I need to find the character that is in certain position, which will be a value entered by the user, but I can't find a way to get the character in said position.

For example: If the user typed in the phrase "I need a plane"
and he selected position number 3, I would need to show the user the letter "e". However, I cannot find a way to get the character in x position.

However, I cannot use an index because the position I need is not defined, it is a value that the user will give, and Python only allows integers to be entered in that section.

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: Huh? This is just `string[position]`

Comment: Why would the integer requirement be a problem?  Convert the user input to an integer first.

Answer (score 0):

You can index a string just like an array in python:

```
s = "I need a plane"
print(s[3])
```

Output:

```
e
```

To get the string and position as user input you can use the `input()` function, and parse the second string to an integer:

```
s = input("Please enter a string: ")
i = input("Please enter an index: ")
i = int(i)
print(s[i])
```

With the input "I need a plane" and "3" the output will be:

```
e
```

Comment: Using names of builtin functions or types (like "str") as variable names is bad style.

Comment: But the thing is, the number I am using, in your example 3, is a variable, a value the user will type in and a value I don't know